# Inner Join on non unique keys, resulting table size

Tags: sql, join

I have Table `a` with of `count(key) = n` and a Table `b` with of `count(key) = m`, where `m>n`. `m` is only bigger, because the key is not unique and there are a lot of duplicates, but every `b.key` is also in `a.key`.

So when I execute

```
SELECT
 count(a.key)
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.key = b.key
```

will it be the size of  `m`, right? Because it will just duplicate the rows of `a` to match `b`, right? If so, does a join exist, where that's not the case and we get a result of size `n`?

Comment: *"will it be the size of m, right?"* yes if every key in `a` is in `b` and vice-versa. *"if so, does a join exist, where that's not the case and we get a result of size n?"* No there isn't. Only because there is lots of ways to achieve that, but each of them give a different output. Please share sample data and desired results and we can help you craft the sql to get there.

Comment: You want to count rows in `a` only where they exist in `b`? *Left semi-join*.

Comment: @Stu yes, exactly.

Comment: Any 2 tables can be joined on any condition. What does "does a join exist" mean? PS Please clarify via edits not comments. PS [mre] PS Your "because" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Justify referencing authoritative documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To count the rows in `a` only once where they exist in `b` use `exists` - it's implied from your question that `key` is unique in `a`:

```
select count(*)
from a
where exists (select * from b where b.key = a.key)
```

Comment: and if the keys in both tables are not unique?

Comment: `count(distinct a.key)` ?